# Written a little time delta function and want to capture results as a numpy array

Tags: python, numpy, datetime

I have a written some code that takes two data_dict lists one containing opening times and one containing closing times.

The functions finds the difference between these two times and returns a figure in hours X.X hours.

IF, the opening and closing times in the lists are not in the correct format (00:00:00), then the function returns '-1'.

It works perfectly, however I want to be able to capture the results and save them as a numpy array.

The results print like this...

```
X
Y
Z
A
X
etc...
```

I am very very new to python and just need some guidance.

Thanks guys.

```
opening_time_arr = data_dict['Open']
closing_time_arr = data_dict['Close']

if len(opening_time_arr) == len(closing_time_arr):
    resultTime = []
for idx, closing_time in enumerate(closing_time_arr):
    try:
        FORMAT = '%H:%M:%S'
        tdelta = datetime.strptime(closing_time, FORMAT) - datetime.strptime(opening_time_arr[idx], FORMAT)
        resultTime.append(tdelta)
        tdelta_h = tdelta.total_seconds()/3600
        print(tdelta_h)
    except ValueError:
        print('-1')
```

The function returns

```
8.0
8.5
6.5
7.5
```

and so on... there is about 250 entries.

How can I take these numbers and convert them to a numpy array without printing the results like my code does currently.

Comment: Accumulate them in a list then make an Numpy ndarray of it.

Comment: As I said, new to python. I wouldn't have a clue how to do that. It took me hours to write that alone.

Comment: What is `resultTime`?  [Numpy Tutorial](https://www.numpy.org/devdocs/user/quickstart.html)

Comment: If I do that then all it captures is the time deltas, not the values...
array([datetime.timedelta(seconds=28800),
       datetime.timedelta(seconds=30600),
       datetime.timedelta(seconds=23400), etc... how can I convert to hours?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oliver - I think you were really close! If `tdelta_h` is your output in hours, then that is what you want to be appending to `resultTime`. After your for loop finishes, then you can convert the list to a numpy array using `np.array()`, and then print out the array if you want to make sure it looks OK.

Here's how I think it should look all together:

```
import numpy as np
opening_time_arr = data_dict['Open']
closing_time_arr = data_dict['Close']

if len(opening_time_arr) == len(closing_time_arr):
    resultTime = []
for idx, closing_time in enumerate(closing_time_arr):
    try:
        FORMAT = '%H:%M:%S'
        tdelta = (datetime.strptime(closing_time, FORMAT) - datetime.strptime(opening_time_arr[idx], FORMAT))

        tdelta_h = tdelta.total_seconds()/3600
        resultTime.append(tdelta_h)

    except ValueError:
        resultTime.append(-1)

np.array(resultTime)
print(resultTime)
```

Hope this helps :)